# Youtube embed won't work without other character or whitespace

Tags: nodes, files

I am not able to embed Youtube video in [embed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/emfield) or in normal body area, when the content is only the video embed code. But if I add any character or a whitespace it works. I am not able to explain to the client why it is like that not explain a logical reason for the same.

Comment: Please improve the title.

Comment: Done. Hope the one i added suffice.

Comment: Looks much better :) Unfortunately you were so fast in changing the question, it doesn't count as an edit, so I can't reverse my vote :( Which module are you using? Adding a link would be a good reason to edit the question again.

Comment: That's ok. :) Well the problem exist even when I embed in the body field with Full HTML filter. The module am using is, https://www.drupal.org/project/emfield